# Протокол канального уровня Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi

Суть вопроса такова: я хочу в качестве учебного проекта придумать и реализовать свой протокол канального уровня. Придумывать буду не я (проект групповой), мне надо это дело имплементировать. Т.е. необходимо получить доступ к канальному уровню сетевого адаптера Wi-Fi: иметь возможность получать статус несущей (занята/свободна) и читать хедер передаваемого по сети кадра данных (причём без предварительной буферизации, т.е. буквально в реальном времени). Соответственно после прочтения хедера устройство будет принимать какие-то решения (читать дальше или спать) ну и т.д. Также в реальном времени нужно читать бикон-сообщения.

С чего можно начать? Я гуглил устройства для Arduino, там только высокоуровневые функции (типа просканировать сеть, подключиться и т.д.). Видимо задача выливается в написание драйвера к Wi-Fi адаптеру. С чего начинать гуглить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете, конечно же, скачать исходники какого-нибудь драйвера wi-fi под linux и ковырять их (я в стародавние времена руками был вынужден собирать себе драйвер для карты на чипсете atheros).

И hostapd вам наверняка будет очень интересен.

А я бы на вай-фай не замахивался. Взял бы тупой модуль-модулятор на 433Mhz (который по лог 1 включает несучку, а по лог 0 - выключает), приемник (а тоже тупой - сверхгенератор), манчестерский код... эээх, молодость...